# Why can't I decrease for all elements in my ArrayList/LinkedList

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, iteration

***Original question :***

Originally, I want to decrease (1) for all elements in MyLinkedList. But, since I cannot use foreach loop in MyLinkedList I first transferred all elements in MyLinkedList to ArrayList then with a foreach loop decreased (1) for all of the elements. But the thing is, I want to do this decrease operation per second.

```
input : 5-6-7

output : 1 second : 4-5-6 
         2 second : 3-4-5 ...
```

***My problem :***

The problem with my code is : it decreases (1) per second for the ith element of ArrayList.

```
input : 5-6-7

output : 1 second 4-6-7
         2 second 4-5-6
         ...
```

Here's my code so far.

```
public void decreaseTime(MyLinkedList l1,MyLinkedList l2) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Node tmp = l1.first;


        /*originally i want to decrease 1 for all elements of mylinkedlist.       
          since i cannot 
          use foreach in mylinkedlist i first transferred 
          elements of mylinkedlist to an Arraylist arr. 
          then decreased 1 for each element.*/

        //lltoarr does copy all mylinkedlist elements to ArrayList arr.
        lltoarr(l1, arr);

        while (tmp != null) {
            // simple sleep method which pauses the program for 1 second.
            sleep();

            int j = 0;

            //decrease operation for each element of arr
            for (int t : arr) {

                //this is a trick for my program to work. you may ignore the next line. 
                int c = tmp.data.length() - 1;


                t--;
                arr.set(j, t);
                // timeNew gets the new time which is the edited t element
                int timeNew = arr.get(j);



                if (somethin) {
                    //copy timeNew to String. i must store the time as string in mylinkedlist.
                    String newData = tmp.data.substring(0, c - 2) + timeNew
                            + "h";


                    tmp.data = newData;
                    System.out.println(tmp.data);
                    sleep();
                    tmp = tmp.next;

                }

                else {
                    String newData = tmp.data.substring(0, c - 1) + timeNew
                            + "h";
                    tmp.data = newData;
                    System.out.println(tmp.data);
                    sleep();
                    tmp = tmp.next;
                }       
                j++;

            } 
            System.out.println(arr);

            }
        }
```

***MyLinkedList class :***

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MyLinkedList {

    Node first, last;


    public void insertFirst(String s) {
        Node n = new Node(s);
        if (first == null) {
            last = n;
        }
        n.next = first;
        first = n;
    }

    public void insertLast(String s) {
        Node n = new Node(s);
        if (first == null) {
            first = n;
        } else {
            last.next = n;
        }
        last = n;
    }


    public void deleteFirst() {
        if (first.next == null) {
            first = null;
            last = null;
        }

        else if (first == null)
            return;
        else
            first = first.next;
    }


    public void lltoarr(MyLinkedList ll, ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        Node tmp = ll.first;
        while (tmp != null) {
            String numberOnly = tmp.data.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            int time = Integer.parseInt(numberOnly);
            arr.add(time);
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }


    //decreaseTime method here


    public void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        Node tmp = first;
        int i = 0;
        while (tmp != null) {
            System.out.print(tmp.data + " - ");
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }

    public int nOfNodes() {
        int n = 0;
        Node tmp = first;
        while (tmp != null) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
            n++;
        }
        return n;
    }


    public Node search(String s) {
        Node tmp = first;
        while (tmp != null) {
            if (tmp.data == s) {
                return tmp;
            } else {
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void llCopy(MyLinkedList ll, MyLinkedList llcopy,int i) {

            llcopy.insertLast(ll.nthNode(i));


    }

    public void insertAfter(String s, Node n) {

        Node nn = new Node(s);
        nn.next = n.next;
        n.next = nn;

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code to see where the issue is? this is an issue where the debugger should be your first point of call

Comment: So you decide which data structure to use based on it's `for-each` compatibility? Why not stick with the `LinkedList` and use a while loop? Copying each element to another list just to use a `for-each` loop is not the way to go.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have to use LinkedList. But I also have to decrease (1) from each elements so I came up with this idea.

Comment: But you're not using `LinkedList`, you're using `MyLinkedList`. Still, if you have to write your own linked list implementation (presumably for a class), why not just make it `Iterable` so that you can use an enhanced for loop with it?

Comment: @Kaan it's not a bad idea but it's also not a good idea. BevynQ's answer is a good way to do it.

Comment: @DavidConrad how can I make my custom LinkedList class iterable?

Comment: In short: implement the `Iterable` interface. But you're going to have to understand how to create an `Iterator` for it. I'm guessing you'll need to read up on that.

Comment: @Kaan I'll add an answer with an example of what David Conrad is talking about. But could you add the code from your `MyLinkedList` class to your question?

Comment: added MyLinkedList class. @JonnyHenly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you are indexing the list is not going to work.

If you want to iterate through the list and adjust each value I would suggest wrapping the Integer value with a holder that has a decrement function

e.g.

```
public IntegerHolder {


    private int value;
....

    public void decrement(){
        this.value--;
    }

}
```

Then you can do this

```
for(IntegerHolder value : list){
    value.decrement();
}
```

Otherwise you could use a ListIterator and remove the old value and insert the decremented value,

```
for(ListIterator<Integer> iter = list.listIterator();iter.hasNext();){
    int value = iter.next(); // get current value
    iter.remove(); // remove it from list
    iter.add(value-1); // insert decremented value where old value was
}
```

Personally I find the foreach loop for collections to be of limited value. Usually I want to access the iterator for some reason and it wont let me.